# Print lines between strings subject to conditions

Tags: regex, awk, sed, r-markdown

I have a(n R Markdown) script that contains plain text, plus delimited chunks of bash code. I would like to extract all of the bash code chunks into a separate document with the title as a chunk above the code as a comment. However, I only want to print code chunks if options `include` and `echo` *are not* found. Example script:

````
Here's some writing. Next code chunk should be included. 

```{bash, chunk-1, option=TRUE}
foo="bar"
```

Now one not to be included because it contains `include`.

```{bash, chunk-2, option=TRUE, include=FALSE}
foo2="bar2"
```

Another code chunk not to be included because it contains `echo`. 

```{bash, chunk-3, option=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
foo3="bar3"
```

Finally one that should be included because `include` and `echo` are not found.

```{bash, chunk-4, option=FALSE, another_option=TRUE}
foo4="bar4"
```
````

Desired output would be

```
# chunk-1 
foo="bar"

# chunk-4
foo4="bar4"
```

The chunk title will always be between the first two commas, other options follow are comma-separated after.

I have been working with `awk`. The following gets the comment write, but does not search for `include` or `echo`.

````
awk '$0 ~ /^```$/ {p=0} 
     $1 ~ /^```{bash/ {p=1; print "\n# " substr($2, 1, length($2)-1); next}
     p'
````

Comment: Except the keyword `bash` in your text file, the question has nothing to do with bash tag.

Comment: Could you please post more clear samples of input and expected output. Your logic of getting sample output is not clear, kindly do edit it and let us know then.

Comment: Please provide just 1 sample input file that has blocks you do and blocks you don't want to match and then the expected output file given that input. Without that it's very difficult to test a potential solution to see if it really works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

````
awk -F ', *' '/^```$/{p = 0} p;
/```{bash/ && !/ (include|echo)=/{print "#", $2; p=1}' file
````

```
# title-of-chunk
# here's some bash code
blah_blah="blah"
```